# Admin url is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, http-status-code-404, admin

I have created a small application in codeigniter. Frontend is running properly where as admin section is not opening.

I'm trying to open as `yourdomain/admin/index.php/user/`(But it showing `404 not found error`).

So how to view the catalog section of admin?

Here is my file structure and file content for admin

```
D:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\views\admin\catalog\catalog_view.php

<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit(__('No direct script access allowed')); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('admin/inc/header'); ?>

<h1><?php echo __('Catalog Manager'); ?></h1>

<p>Coming Soon...</p>


<?php $this->load->view('admin/inc/footer'); ?>


D:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\admin\catalog\catalog.php

<?php
/**
 * Admin User Controller
 */
class User extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::MY_Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data = '';

        //---
        $html_string = $this->load->view('admin/catalog/catalog_view', $data, true); //Get view data in place of sending to browser.

        Library('process')->view($html_string);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide `config/routes.php`

Answer (score 1):

you can't access it in that way `yourdomain/admin/index.php/user/` you have to try first `site.com/index.php/admin/...`

but you have to be sure you created a controller named `controller/admin.php` which loads your `views/admin/` pages

> cause if you don't want to touch the CI core or extend it the rule is
>   :
>
> ```
> http://www.site.com/index.php/controller/method/params
> ```

so in your case i would do:

```
class Admin exntends CI_Controller{
 function index(){
 //admin home page
//www.site.com/index.php/admin
}
function users(){
//admin users page
//www.site.com/index.php/admin/users
}

//... and so on

}
```

No Routes needed and if you want to remove **index.php** from your url just place this `htaccess` in your project root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Or create `admin` folder inside controller directory. `application/controller/admin/...` works in CI 2.1.3

Comment: @HashemQolami well yeah as you want!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a good htaccess setup?
Without htaccess you can access admin->index(); this with index.php/admin/index/

Your admin controller file isn't in the right order:
/application/controllers/admin/catalog/catalog.php

Without routing (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) you cannot make this work, and you need to change your class name from user to catalog.

Ideally, you move the controller to /controllers/admin.php. 
Then you can do index.php/admin and the index function will show. No routing needed what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the route file few settings and easily set the admin URL.

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```